# API for reply to reviews in App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there any API for replying to customer review in App Store similar with Google Play Store API:
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews

I need a way to reply the customer review in App Store for our customer service agent via our website (back-office) . I have seen there is some solution that is provide the API for reply to the application store reviews so i think it is possible. I only can find the way to fetch the reviews data (xml/json) but not to reply to it.

Comment: No, there is no API to reply to reviews. you can Reply from iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can reply to customer reviews in [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com) by going to My Apps > [Your app] > Activity > iOS App, then hit "Reply" in the right size of the box for the review that you wanna reply to. You can find a more detailed guide on the [iTunes Connect Help Page](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/devc867852db). As far as I can tell, there's no API to do this programmatically, if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, i know we can reply from iTunes Connect. However, the requirement is to create one menu to maintain all the feedback from customer including replies from google/app store in one place. 

So, we need the API or other way to retrieve data from customer reviews and reply to it.

One of the users said in his previous company he can reply to the customer review (Google/App) store from his company back-office system.

Comment: There's no publicly-available API for that, unfortunately

Comment: This answer may or may not get updated in the future. It looks like Apple has a workshop on automating interactions with iTunes Connect and such on Thursday called "Automating App Store Connect" that you can watch in the WWDC app after it's filmed. It looks like they may be introducing an API for this

Answer (score -2):

You can use AppFollow.io API for reply to Reviews in App Store or Google Play: https://appfollow.docs.apiary.io/#reference/0/api-methods/5.-review-reply

It's super easy: just setup account and use one of libraries for js or python. 
https://github.com/AppFollow/appfollow-api-js
https://github.com/AppFollow/appfollow-api-python

Answer (score -5):

There's no "official" API from Apple, but we at Appfigures recently opened the one we built for our analytics service up, so you can read and reply to app reviews programatically. + it works for both Apple and Google.

Replying with our API requires that you first look up the review you want to reply to and get its ID. Then `POST` your reply with the ID:

```
POST https://api.appfigures.com/reviews/{review_id}/response

{
  content: "Thank you for letting us know! That's something we're actually working to improve "
}
```

Documentation: https://docs.appfigures.com/api/reference/v2/reviews

Comment: I think you should be far more up-front about costs for this:  the MINIMUM pricing plan that allows this is $200 per month